# iOS App Development (Maximum number of certificates generated)

Tags: xcode

Всем здравствуйте.
Не знал, что возможно генерировать всего лишь 3 сертификата iOS App Development. И сейчас xCode не может определить подпись. Кто-то сталкивался с этой проблемой и как можно решить?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: xCode]

Сертификат мой должен был скоро закончиться и решил новый сгенерировать. Вроде смог сгенерировать, но вот что в xCode начал писать.

Заранее спасибо!!!

Comment: [Apple Developer account error: Maximum number of certificates generated (development)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52673303/2881286)

Comment: [Maximum number of certificates generated](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/77131)